# Store source permalink on XMLRPC calls

Tags: filters, actions, xml-rpc

In a theme I'm developing, I need to link to the source post when the post has been stored using XMLRPC. That implies that every time Wordpress asks for a permalink (using get_permalink()) the theme will return a previously saved link. That's accomplished by adding a new filter:

```
add_action('the_permalink', 'filterPermalink');

function filterPermalink($url) {
    $permalink = get_previously_saved_permalink(get_the_ID());
    return $permalink? $permalink : $url;
}
```

That's not the problem (by the moment). The problem is, how to make the same with the *metaWeblog.newPost* function.

I've already tried something like this:

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_methods','xml_rpc_functions_to_add');

function xml_rpc_functions_to_add($args) {
    $args['metaWeblog.newPost'] = 'add_permalink';
    return $args;
}

function add_permalink($args) {
    // Do it
}
```

What I need is to know how to call the previous 'metaWeblog.newPost' from 'add_permalink'.

Comment: You're trying to do two things. Your *working* code calls `get_previously_saved_permalink()` to replace the standard link with one saved elsewhere (post meta perhaps).  But now you're trying to hook in to *save* a different permalink via XMLRPC?

Comment: The idea is simple: assign a source link (given by XMLRPC protocol) to each post so the permalink filter could read and use it. Now I've get add_permalink to work, I've edited the question removing the text where I said that wordpress was not executing this part.

Answer (score 1):

From look at source `metaWeblog.newPost` seems to be processed in `wp_xmlrpc_server->mw_newPost()` method.

At the end of this method there is following hook call:

```
do_action( 'xmlrpc_call_success_mw_newPost', $post_ID, $args );
```

which seems to be very fitting to process and save any additional information for post that have just been created by its ID provided.